# How to decide which Activity will start after the next in android

Tags: android

Hi there I want to call an Activity an decide which is the next activity to start after the Dialog finished like:

```
    Intent dialog_intent = new Intent(_parent, MyActivityA.class);
    dialog_intent.putExtra(MyActivityA.EXTRA_PARENT, MyActivityB.class);
```

I am getting the extra like this in the Oncreate of MyActivityA:

```
    Type _parent = null; // this is a class variable 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            String key = it.next();

            if(key.equals(EXTRA_PARENT))
                _parent = (Type)bundle.get(EXTRA_PARENT);
        }
    }
```

in the finishDialog method I do this :

```
public void finishDialog(View v) 
{ 
    try 
    {
        Intent intent = null; 
        if(_parent != null && _parent instanceof Activity)
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, _parent.getClass());
        }
        else
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, DefaultActivity.class);
        }
        if(intent != null)
        {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        finish();
    }
```

2 Questions:

Why does _parent instaneof Activity not work. I think MyActivity is a Type which inherits of Activity
Trying to start the activity does not work. But if i put in

```
 new Intent(this,MyActivityB.class);
```

it works! What am I doing wrong. Is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass integer value and map it to corresponding activity.

```
Intent dialog_intent = new Intent(_parent, MyActivityA.class);
dialog_intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PARENT", 1);
```

Now in your activity get this EXTRA_PARENT and call activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int extraParent = extras.getInt("EXTRA_PARENT");
if(extraParent == 1)
{
    Intent dialog_intent = new Intent(_parent, MyActivityB.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i thought about a more dynamically solution .... Of course this will work, but I am bound to implemented options and cannot throw something  new to the dialog....

Comment: You can write a Util function that will give you activity class name based on integer and you logic will be at one place and if you need to show another activity you just need to updated that function.

Comment: yeah you are right but i still do not want to update any function because this library should not be changed!